# Neatest ways to extract pairs from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas

Given the following pandas DataFrame:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame([{'Campaign': 'Campaign X', 'Date': '24-09-2014', 'Spend': 1.34, 'Clicks': 241}, {'Campaign': 'Campaign Y', 'Date': '24-08-2014', 'Spend': 2.89, 'Clicks': 12}, {'Campaign': 'Campaign X', 'Date': '24-08-2014', 'Spend': 1.20, 'Clicks': 1}, {'Campaign': 'Campaign Z2', 'Date': '24-08-2014', 'Spend': 4.56, 'Clicks': 13}] )
```

[image]

I wish to first extract Campaign-Spend pairs, first summing where applicable when a campaign has multiple entries (as is the case for campaign *X* in this example). With minimal pandas knowledge, I find myself doing:

```
summed = mydf.groupby('Campaign', as_index=False).sum()
campaignspends = zip(summed['Campaign'], summed['Spend'])
campaignspends = dict(campaignspends)
```

I'm guessing pandas or python itself has a one-liner for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can pull out the column of interest from a groupby object using `["Spend"]`:

```
>>> campaignspends
{'Campaign Y': 2.8900000000000001, 'Campaign Z2': 4.5599999999999996, 'Campaign X': 2.54}
>>> mydf.groupby("Campaign")["Spend"].sum()
Campaign
Campaign X     2.54
Campaign Y     2.89
Campaign Z2    4.56
Name: Spend, dtype: float64
>>> mydf.groupby("Campaign")["Spend"].sum().to_dict()
{'Campaign Y': 2.8900000000000001, 'Campaign Z2': 4.5599999999999996, 'Campaign X': 2.54}
```

Here I've added the `to_dict()` call (`dict(mydf..etc)` will also work), although note that depending on what you're planning to do next, you might not need to convert from a Series to a dictionary at all.  For example,

```
>>> s = mydf.groupby("Campaign")["Spend"].sum()
>>> s["Campaign Z2"]
4.5599999999999996
```

works as you'd expect.